# Can't pass object from a method to a data variable?

Tags: vue.js

**On mounted** -> **Calls** the `GoogleSignIn()` **method** which gets `var user` from the Google account and then I made it pass the object from `var user` to a data variable called `localUser`. But, nothing happens and I don't even get an error message when I try to display it in the `<span>{{ localUser.displayName }}</span>`.

**What I've tried was using**: `this.$data.localUser = user`, which is a Vue 0x reference, but it didn't work. 
Also I've tried setting the `localUser` type to `Object` or `String`.
I've played more with it, but couldn't make it work after more than an hour and a half.

Only thing that worked for me so far was doing a console log `console.log("Localuser:" + this.localUser.displayName)` after setting `this.localUser = user;` (both in the method)

```js
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img class="v" alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/cbsc3-n4s6k.svg">
    <span>{{ localUser.displayName }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import router from '../router'

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  components: {
    
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      localUser: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    GoogleSignIn: function (event) {
      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      firebase.auth().languageCode = 'pt';


      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          // If already signed in.
          console.log(user.displayName);
          this.localUser = user;
          // This console.log actually works and logs the Google account name
          console.log("Localuser:" + this.localUser.displayName)
          // router.push("Home");
        } else {
          // If no one is signed in.
          firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

                console.log("Logged in.");
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var user = result.user;
                this.localUser = user;
                console.log("Localuser:" + this.localUser.displayName)

          }).catch(function(error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                var email = error.email;
                // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                var credential = error.credential;
                console.log(errorMessage);
          });

        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Mounted");
    this.GoogleSignIn();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When you call `this.localUser` inside the firebase auth function, `this` then becomes a reference inside that function. So outside of that, you could do `let self = this;` then call `self.localUser = user` or convert in to ES6 syntax instead of `onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {})` you can do `onAuthStateChanged( (user) => {})`

Comment: Thank you very much @swonder, worked perfectly!

Comment: Happy to help. :)